# How can I search the man pages?

Tags: ssh, manpage

I need to find a an option for ssh but the listing is to long when I do

```
man ssh
```

It appears that the man page is being opened in an editor of some kind and there is a colon prompt.

Comment: That editor is often a pager, see `$PAGER` and `less`

Comment: First of all, do *not* use the nix tag! Have you read its description? Nix is a package manager. How is your question related to it? Second, Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask such question. They should go to Linux/Unix StackExchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a standard configuration (pagertype) you can enter a slash `/` and then the text you search for.

After searched for a text, press `n` for further occurences of the text.

**Edit**

It is not recommended to open a man page in an editor. You had to force the editor to read the man page text from stdin. e.g. for nano this feature is added in newer versions  (>2.2 ?) only. And also if the stdin is redirected the groff control sequences which are reponsible for formatting the pages, won't work. And an editor is not a pager, i.e. space-key prints a white space charater and does not move to the next page.

But theoretically you can setup the environment variable $PAGER with `export PAGER="<your pager/editor>"` (on a bash-like shell). e.g. for nano `export PAGER="nano -"`.